# Visual Studio 2010 Reporting - String Replace + Convert

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion, reporting, vb.net-2010, sql-server-data-tools

Hi from my database I have a field that will contain a value with a currency symbol before it, so for example, £100 or $100

I have then in a table got a group of records that meet a certain criteria. I want to be able to add all the costs up and display them in the field

So I need to remove the currency symbol, convert to decimal and finally add the items together.

I have tried along the lines of the following

```
=Sum(Replace(!Fieldsnew_Cost.Value,"£","")CDec(!Fieldsnew_Cost.Value))
```

But so far have been unsuccessful

Anyone have any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to do the transaction in database side. just try below code:

```
select sum(convert(int,right(tb_column,len(tb_column)-1))) as Cost
```